# Imagenes de HTML no aparecen en chrome pero si explorer/firefox

Tags: javascript, html, python, chrome

Estoy desarrollando un codigo en jupyter notebook y exportando los resultados de este a un archivo html.

El problema, es que cuando abro el archivo html resultante en el navegador chrome las iamgenes no aperecen, sin embargo, si lo abro con explorer/firefox si que aperecen

A esto añadir, que cuando lo abro en chrome y no aprecen, si que aperece el recuadro donde deberian ir, y si clicko en la imgen y le doy a abrir en nueva pestaña, si que aparece, por lo tanto, descarto un problema de ruta.

Intuyo que tiene que ser algo de resolucion. Dejo el codigo:

```
heat_map = sb.heatmap(df_matriz_4, ax=ax, cmap='Blues_r', annot=True, xticklabels=[f'Positive: {Variable_objetivo_names[0]}' ,f'Negative: {Variable_objetivo_names[1]}'], yticklabels=[f'Positive {Variable_objetivo_names[0]}' ,f'Negative: {Variable_objetivo_names[1]}'])
ax.set_title(Variable_objetivo + ' '+ 'Heat map')
file_name = f"heat_map_4"
file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( file_name))
plt.savefig(
file_path, bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300,
    )
plt.close(1)
```

Asi llamo a la imagen (dentro del mismo jupyter)

```
<br><img src="heat_map_4.png" width="400"
     height="341"/><br>
```

Asi estoy exportando mis resultados de jupyter a un archvo html:

```
def write_to_textFile(file):
    f= open('output_2.html', 'w',encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(file)
    f.close()

write_to_textFile(result)
```

Comment: Estás en la versión en Español, edita la pregunta por favor, caso contrario quedará cerrada :D

Comment: Has revisado si algún bloqueador de publicidad en el navegador te está causando el problema?

Comment: elimina tus datos de navegación en especifico los almacenados en caché

Comment: A veces basta con un `ctrl + f5`...

Comment: No tengo ningun bloqueador de anuncios, y lo he probado en dos pcs distintos por si acas, y ocurre el mismo problema en chrome. Eliminando los datos almacenados en caché lo mismo..